# ASP.NET Razor Layout with two Partials, each one with a @Model

Tags: asp.net, forms, razor

In the WebSite (ASP.NET Razor) that I'm doing, I have two PartialViews: Subscribe Newsletter and Contact Form. Each one of this forms has his own @model.

In the Contact Form (with 3 fields: Name, Email and Message), I want to put some validation, and if there are any errors, show it to the user.
The problem it's, when I get the error, I receive an error saying that I cannot deliver the ContactObject to the Newsletter form.

I know that I need to use jQuery and Ajax on this, but I have no clue how can I do this.

Someone can throw me a hand and send me a small example how can I do this with this two partial views?

NOTE: I don't want to create a super-object with both models.

Regards
Paulo Aboim Pinto
Odivelas - Portugal

Answer (score 1):

Make each partial it's own html form submitting to their own actions. Then it will work as designed.

Comment: but that's I have... I think:

Comment: In the ContactUs I have this: 

@model bizSimplex.WebSite.Models.Contact
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ContactUsForm";
    Layout = "_mainPageMasterWithoutFooter.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("ContactUsPost", "Home"))
{   
...
}

In the SubscribeNewsletter I have


@model bizSimplex.WebSite.Models.SITEtblNewsletterSubscriber
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubscribeNewsLetter", "Newsletter"))    
{
...
}


as you can see I have a HTML form on each partial View. The problem it's with the @model

Comment: You should post a bit more code in the question, very hard to follow in the comments.